# We roll a dice until we get 6 twice. What's the most likely place for the first 6? What is the probability that this 'guess' is correct?

Tags: probability-theory, bayes-theorem

We roll a dice until we get six twice ( we stop after the second 6 ). What is the most likely location of the first six? What is the probability that the modus is the actual location of the first six?


My Attempt:

There is this concept of
*forever young*,
wherever we tossed out first six, the probability that we toss the second six on the $n$-th throw after the first six is
$$
\frac{1}{6} \cdot \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{n-1}
$$
This is a monotonically decreasing function. Thus the maximum is attained when $n=1$, which means if we the second six is tossed on the $n$-th toss, we first 6 is most likely tossed on the $n-1$-th toss.

Then, I use Bayes Theorem,
$$
\mathbb{P} \left( F_{n-1}|E  \right) 
=
\frac{\mathbb{P}  \left( E|F_{n-1}  \right)\cdot \mathbb{P}\left(F_{n-1}\right)}  {\sum_i\mathbb{P}  \left( E|F_i  \right) \cdot \mathbb{P}\left(F_i\right)}
$$
where E is the event that the second six is tossed on the $n$-th toss, and $F_i$ is the event that the first six is tossed on the $i$-th toss. This is equal to
$$
\frac {(\frac{1}{6}) \cdot (\frac{5}{6}^{n-2} \cdot \frac{1}{6})}   {\sum_i (\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6}^{n-i-1}) \cdot (\frac{5}{6}^{i-1} \cdot \frac{1}{6})}
$$

This simplifies to 1 unfortunately, since we can cross out $(\frac{1}{6})^2$, and the sum on the denominator is independent of $i$, being equal to $ (\frac{5}{6})^{n-2}  $.


Can someone please point out my mistake here?

Comment: I just realized that it doesn't simplify to 1. Since we have $n-1$ terms on the summation, it simplifies to $\frac{1}{n-1}$, which is still bad anyway, since the modus is $\frac{1}{n-1}$, and the distribution is not uniform, and we have $n-1$ terms, which means it won't add up to 1.

Comment: Is that two consecutive sixes, or 0 or more non-sixes, one six, 0 or more non-sixes, the second six?

Comment: Here is a scenario, our first 4 tosses are non 6-s, the 5th toss is a 6, the 6-8th tosses are non 6-s, then the 9th toss is another 6. We stop after the ninth toss because the second six has just came out.

Comment: Are you told the number of the throw of the second six and trying to derive the most likely location for the first?  If not, why are you worried about the second six at all, as the question just asks for the first six.  The rest of the rolls don't matter.  It is important to get the question right.

Comment: In the question, the location of the 2nd six is told to us, which is at the nth toss. We're trying to determine out of these n tosses where is most likely location of the first six.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, before I critique your method, the answer to :

> What is the most likely location of the first six?
> What is the probability that the modus is the actual location of the first six?

I am unfamilar with the term modus.  However, the most likely location of the
first 6 is **independent** of your *intent* to keep rolling the die after the
first 6 comes up.

Therefore, by the analysis that you already gave, the most likely location of
the first 6 is the first roll.  I wikipedia-googled on modus; it seems to be
a synonym for mode, which is the same as how I interpreted the question.

As for critiquing your math, I found it perfect, except that you overlooked
that the denominator is the **sum** of $(n-1)$ terms, each of whom compute
to the same value.

This means that $p[(F_{(n-1)}|E] = \frac{1}{n-1}.$

Comment: Which means if we fix the 2nd toss as the nth toss, all of the previous n-1 tosses has equal probability of being the first 6. However, is it also not true that the probability of the 2nd toss being 'far' from the first toss is relatively smaller, as if the n is very big, it is most likely because it took us a long time to roll the first 6? I fully understood your reasoning, however I was stuck on the second mindset, and even now I can't explain the flaw in my logic.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes "However, is it also not true that the probability of the 2nd toss being 'far' from the first toss is relatively smaller,..."?  That is exactly right.  That means (for example) that if the first 6 occurs on the 17th roll, then the most likely slot for the 2nd 6 is the 18th roll.  At the same time, if you are given that the 2nd 6 occurred on the 18th roll, the chance that the 1st 6 occurred on the 17th roll is (1/17).  I see no conflict here.  Any questions?

Comment: There's a simple symmetry explanation as well -- e.g. take $n=4$ and denote non-$6$ by $x$, then you are asking which of these sequences is more/less likely than any other: $6xx6, x6x6, xx66$ -- but it seems clear that they are equally likely. And similarly for any $n$.